# iOS scrollview with grayscale image on inactive and normal image on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, gpuimage

**The statement**

The images in scrollview will gain colour when the scrollview is scrolling and be grayscaled after scroll has ended or is not scrolling.

**Contents in scrollview**

The scrollview will `UIView` and `UIImage` as a direct descendant. The image may or may not be contained in every `UIView`. Each `UIView` may have texts, texts & images and images.

**Resolution of images**

The image resolution will be small, something like **300x150**, **450x150**

**What have we done ?**

We have come across [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) Framework by [Brad Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson). The framework is impressive to say the least, and we have been fascinated with everything the framework offers.

Our initial tests on performance by the framework is satisfactory.

We have managed to use `GPUImageGrayscaleFilter` to transform images into grayscale images when they are inserted in the scrollview.

**Optimization**

We have decided to apply filters on images that are visible in the scrollview. This will significantly reduce the load

**Where are we stuck now ?**

There are two ways we could get the color back to the image

1. remove `GPUImageGrayscaleFilter` from the UIImage. *We have not been able to do this*.
2. remove the `UIImage` and insert the original image. The images are being downloaded with cache policy of `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad`. *inserting the downloaded image will not be a issue.*

***Either way, we will be applying filter and inserting same image number of times***. We are not certain about this part. Are we missing a simple trick ?

I would like to thank everyone in advance for their time and response :)

### UPDATE & SOLUTION

I was able to achieve this using GPUImage.

Steps involved

1. Assign normal image to `UIControlStateNormal` of `UIButton` and grayscale transformed image from `GPUImageGrayScaleFilter` to `UIControlStateHighlighted`
2. Trigger state change when you want image to gain color
3. Trigger state change when you want image to be grayed

The performance of this carousel is very smooth. There is a spike in GPU Time Elapsed profile in the begining but afterwards its absolutely zero.

I will update the profiling stats as we progress with our tests.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Sounds like you're working on a very interesting topic. But, where is the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a limited number of images, you can download a normal image, create a grayscale copy and save both to disk. 
In the scroll view, instead of UIImageView, use **UIButton** with type custom and clear background color.
UIButton lets you set a `different image for different control states`.
Set the normal and grayscale images for normal and selected/disabled state. For the views which do not need an image just don't set an image. 
Change the button's state when scrolling begins and ends, in the delegate.

P.S. : Have you considered scroll view's more sophisticated descendants 'UITableView' and 'UICollectionView' instead of using simple scroll view? They'll save you a lot of scrolling related code and time.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Swapnil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219971/swapnil-luktuke), I was able to achieve a carousel like effect that transforms image to grayscale when inactive and gains colour when scrolling.

---

### Implementation

1. Set different images for different states

   ```
   UIbutton* someButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

   [someButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


   GPUImageGrayscaleFilter* grayScaleFilter = [[GPUImageGrayscaleFilter alloc] init];

   [someButton setBackgroundImage:[grayScaleFilter imageByFilteringImage:imageToBeTransformed] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
   ```
2. Change state when scrollview starts scrolling (gain colour)

   ```
     -(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
          for(id view in scrollView.subviews) {
               if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                     [self highlightButtons];
               }
          }
      }
   ```

   Some of the views in my scrollview did not require this effect so I filtered them out using tags

   ```
     -(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
          for(id view in scrollView.subviews) {
               if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                     if(((UIView*)view).tag == kRequiresScrollEffectChange)
                         [self highlightButtonsInView:(UIView*) view];
               }
          }
      }
   ```
3. Change state back to normal when scrollview is done scrolling

   ```
    - (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate 
    {
          if (!decelerate) {
              [self normalizeHighlightedButtonsInScrollview:scrollView];
          }
    }

    -(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIView *)scrollView
    {
          [self normalizeHighlightedButtonsInScrollview:scrollView];
    }
   ```
4. Highlight buttons to gain colour with animation and normalize back to gray scale image

   ```
    -(void) highlightButtonsInView:(UIView*) view    
    {
        for(id object in view.subviews) 
        {
             if([object isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]
             {
                  [self changeButtonState:object willHighlight:YES];
             }
        }
    }

    -(void) normalizeButtonsInView:(UIView*) view    
    {
        for(id object in view.subviews) 
        {
             if([object isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]
             {
                  [self changeButtonState:object willHighlight:NO];
             }
        }
    }

    -(void) normalizeHighlightedButtonsInScrollview:(UIScrollView*) scrollView
    {
        for(id view in scrollView.subviews)
        {
             if(((UIView*)view).tag == kRequiresScrollEffectChange)
             {
                 [self normalizeButtonsInView:view];
             }
        }
    }

    -(void) changeButtonState:(UIButton)button willHighlight:(BOOL) enableDisable
    {
        [UIView transitionWithView:button
                                 duration:2.3
                                  options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                               animations:^{ [button setHighlighted:enableDisable]; }
                               completion:nil];
    }
   ```